# Maximum and minimum numbers of combinations in a double Latin Square

Tags: optimization, latin-square

Let's have a double 6x6 Latin Square (see Figure 1). You can see that this Latin Square has thirteen combinations (see Figure 2). Can you make a double Latin Square that contains the maximum number of combinations and another with a minimum number of combinations? Only numbers from 1 to 6 are allowed.
[image: double Latin Square with combinations]

Comment: To be clear, your example in Figure 1 contains 13 pairs (all but 2,6 and 3,5)?

Comment: Is 1,2 and 2,1 two different combinations or is that considered the same combination?

Comment: 1,2 and 2,1 is one combination.

Comment: Where does 2,6 appear in your example?

Comment: My example is for demonstration purposes. It is up to you to find the maximum number of combinations.

Comment: Your example claims to cover both 2,6 and 3,5, but I don't see them in any of the 36 2x2 squares.  Also, is 1,1 considered a combination?  Please clarify the rules.

Comment: I made no such claim. I merely presented an example as a demonstration. Yes, 1,1 is a combination.

Comment: @RobPratt Figure 2 is just the list of all possible combinations, it's not the list of combinations of figure 1.

Comment: Figure 2 shows the combinations present in Figure 1.

Comment: How are 2,6 and 3,5, which are both listed in Figure 2, present in Figure 1?

Comment: My mistake. Sorry.  Thank you for catching it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minimal:

> 3 distinct unordered pairs:

> ```
>      16 25 34 43 52 61
>      25 34 43 52 61 16
>      34 43 52 61 16 25
>      43 52 61 16 25 34
>      52 61 16 25 34 43
>      61 16 25 34 43 52
> ```

Maximal:

> 21 distinct unordered pairs (which is all of them):

> ```
>      11 22 33 44 55 66
>      23 34 45 56 61 12
>      35 46 51 62 13 24
>      52 63 14 25 36 41
>      44 55 66 11 22 33
>      66 11 22 33 44 55
> ```

Comment: Confirmed via integer linear programming.